# Create external hive table using partial data from hbase table

Tags: hive, hbase

I can create a hive table like this which takes data from hbase:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE app_store_data
(key string,
type string,
name string,
country string,
price float)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf:_type,cf:name, cf:country, cf:price")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "DEBUG_items_app_store");
```

However, my hbase table contains two types of items, one is 'apps' and other is 'reviews', a key called _type defines which type of item it is. I want to create two separate external tables in hive from same hbase table, one which will take rows with _type = 'review' and other which will take rows which have _type = 'app'. How do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can't do it on the fly. hive-hbase handler doesn't provide any such DDL feature to apply filter.
Possibly you could create your own solution to achieve it:

- Add a TBLPROPERTIES in DDL to categorize type of records, particular table point to- `_type`(apps, reviews). e.g. TBLPROPERTIES('record.type','_apps')
- Download [hive hbase handler](https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/master/hbase-handler) source code, set start and end row key or rowkey filter to `HBaseScanRange.java` inside setup method. Extract filter criteria from TBLPROPERTIES. Read [custom serde](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DeveloperGuide#DeveloperGuide-HowtoWriteYourOwnSerDe) for more details.
- Use your custom hive hbase handler.

Otherwise, create managed tables-

```
create table app_store_data_apps as 
select * from app_store_data where key like '%_apps';

create table app_store_data_reviews as 
select * from app_store_data where key like '%_reviews';
```